# symfony DateTimeToTimestampTransformer

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to get the unix timestamp but can't seems to get it. 
I have form where the users need to select the date and time

```
$builder->add('time', 'datetime', array(
            'input'  => 'timestamp',
        ))
```

More info: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#input

But all i have is an array.. when i need an integet with unix timestamp

```
$time = $formData['time'];

print_r($time);
```

Output:

```
Array(
 [date] => Array(
        [year] => 2015
        [month] => 6
        [day] => 7
    )
[time] => Array(
        [hour] => 6
        [minute] => 6
    ))
```

When I need something like 1443197171

Comment: just let them select datetime and use ```$dt->format('U')```

Comment: $time = $formData['time']->format('U'); gives me Error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Comment: You need to set ```'input' => 'datetime'```

Comment: I tried with that its still an array...

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the right file?... That seems off

Comment: Yes...

$builder->add('time', 'datetime', array(
                'input'  => 'datetime',
                'format'=>'U'
            ))

it returns array

Comment: This is how my controller looks like

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3eb6e8a286a1a1c5367f

note:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're looking at the `POST` data that comes back from the form which is different from the normalised data that the Symfony Forms component provides.

The visual representation is controlled by the `widget` option of the field, so in your case you probably want to set it to `single_text` like so:

```
$builder->add('time', 'datetime', array(
    'input'  => 'timestamp',
    'widget' => 'single_text',
));
```

Even then you'll probably get back an array with separate `date` and `time` entries. What you want to do is get the "data" attribute from the form component, e.g.

```
$form->get('time')->getData();
```

This gets the field component and then retrieves the data. As the entry you linked to states:

> The value that comes back from the form will also be normalized back into this format.

At this point it might be best to look into the [model / view structure](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#about-model-and-view-transformers) of the form components.